# Using R code to reorganize data frame by randomly selecting one row from each combination

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Subject  N   S
Sub1-1   3   1
Sub1-2   3   1
Sub1-3   3   1
Sub1-4   3   1
Sub2-1   3   1
Sub2-2   3   1
Sub2-3   3   1
Sub2-4   3   1
Sub3-1   3   2
Sub3-2   3   2
Sub3-3   3   2
Sub4-1   3   2
Sub4-2   3   2
Sub4-3   3   2
Sub5-1   3   2
Sub5-2   3   2
Sub6-1   1   1
Sub6-2   1   1
Sub6-3   1   1
Sub7-1   1   1
Sub7-2   1   1
Sub7-3   1   1
Sub8-1   1   1
Sub8-2   1   1
Sub8-3   1   2
Sub9-1   1   2
Sub9-2   1   2
Sub1-1   1   2
Sub1-2   1   2
Sub1-3   1   2
Sub5-1   1   2
Sub5-2   1   2
Sub1-5   2   1
Sub1-6   2   1
Sub1-7   2   1
Sub1-5   2   1
Sub2-6   2   1
Sub2-5   2   1
Sub2-6   2   1
Sub2-7   2   1
Sub3-8   2   2
Sub3-5   2   2
Sub3-6   2   2
Sub4-7   2   2
Sub4-5   2   2
Sub4-6   2   2
Sub5-7   2   2
Sub5-8   2   2
```

As you can see in this data frame there are 6 different combinations in the N and S columns, and 8 consecutive rows of each combination. I want to create a new data frame where one row from each combination (be it 3 & 1 or 1 & 2) is randomly selected and then put into a new data frame so there are 8 consecutive rows of each different combination. That way the entire data frame of all 48 rows is completely reorganized. Is this possible in R code?

Edit: The desired output would be something like this, but repeating until all 48 rows are full and the subject number for each row would have be random because it is a randomly selected row of each N & S combo.

```
Subject  N   S
         3   1
         1   1
         3   2
         1   2
         2   2
         2   1
         2   2
         3   2
         2   1
         1   1
         3   1
         1   2
```

Comment: Show us desired output as well.

Comment: Ok, I tried to explain the output I want

Answer (score 1):

A solution using functions from `dplyr`.

```
# Load package 
library(dplyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(N, S) %>%
  sample_n(size = 1)

# View the result
dt2

## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   N, S [6]
#  Subject     N     S
#    <chr> <int> <int>
#1  Sub6-3     1     1
#2  Sub5-1     1     2
#3  Sub1-5     2     1
#4  Sub5-8     2     2
#5  Sub2-4     3     1
#6  Sub3-1     3     2
```

#### Update: Reorganize the row

The following randomize all rows.

```
dt3 <- dt %>% slice(sample(1:n(), n()))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Subject  N   S
Sub1-1   3   1
                 Sub1-2   3   1
                 Sub1-3   3   1
                 Sub1-4   3   1
                 Sub2-1   3   1
                 Sub2-2   3   1
                 Sub2-3   3   1
                 Sub2-4   3   1
                 Sub3-1   3   2
                 Sub3-2   3   2
                 Sub3-3   3   2
                 Sub4-1   3   2
                 Sub4-2   3   2
                 Sub4-3   3   2
                 Sub5-1   3   2
                 Sub5-2   3   2
                 Sub6-1   1   1
                 Sub6-2   1   1
                 Sub6-3   1   1
                 Sub7-1   1   1
                 Sub7-2   1   1
                 Sub7-3   1   1
                 Sub8-1   1   1
                 Sub8-2   1   1
                 Sub8-3   1   2
                 Sub9-1   1   2
                 Sub9-2   1   2
                 Sub1-1   1   2
                 Sub1-2   1   2
                 Sub1-3   1   2
                 Sub5-1   1   2
                 Sub5-2   1   2
                 Sub1-5   2   1
                 Sub1-6   2   1
                 Sub1-7   2   1
                 Sub1-5   2   1
                 Sub2-6   2   1
                 Sub2-5   2   1
                 Sub2-6   2   1
                 Sub2-7   2   1
                 Sub3-8   2   2
                 Sub3-5   2   2
                 Sub3-6   2   2
                 Sub4-7   2   2
                 Sub4-5   2   2
                 Sub4-6   2   2
                 Sub5-7   2   2
                 Sub5-8   2   2",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not very experienced with R. What is this: %>% a placeholder for?

Comment: It is called pipe operator. Please see this (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others#t=201706291725101458687)

Comment: Is there any way to edit the code so I can have all the originals rows organized like this without repeating? Not just 6 of them?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. Do you want just reorganize the rows?

Comment: Please see my update. No `group_by` is required if you just want to randomize the rows.